# Find the area of a triangle that we don't know its base and height?

Tags: geometry

[image: triangle]

firstly find the area of m . And we don't have any clue just a picture   ..

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? Have you been able to prove anything about the figure? Are there any relevant ideas that you think might show up in the solution? The more information we have, the more helpful we can be with our hints/solutions.

Comment: I think this is related to Ceva theorem. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I assume the areas of $BFE$ and $BFC$ are $4$, $10$ respectively. 
$$\frac{A(BFE)}{EF}=\frac{A(BCF)}{FC}\Rightarrow EF=2k,\quad FC=5k$$
$$\frac{A(FCD)}{FD}=\frac{A(BCF)}{FB}\Rightarrow FD=4a,\quad FB=5a$$
So 
$$\frac{5S-4}{2k}=\frac{8+4S}{5k}$$
 I think you can do the rest of it.

Comment: Nice answer and nice picture!